# Using upsert with the updateOne() method to perform an update operation

Tags: mongodb

I’m using upsert with the updateOne() method as bellow to perform an update.

```
   db.practice.updateOne(
     {“title”:“Night Life”}, 
     {$set: detail}, 
     {upsert: true} 
   )
```

My query returns the following:

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "matchedCount" : 0,
    "modifiedCount" : 0,
     "upsertedId" : ObjectId("5f8884fed29ded706c3c6737")
}
```

Below is the detail variable:

```
let detail = {
  “title” : “Night Life”,
  “year” : 2021,
  “rated” : “PG-13”,
  “released” : 2021,
  “runtime” : 60,
  “countries” : [
    “USA”,
    “UK”
  ],
  “genres” : [
    “comedy”,
    “drama”
  ],
  “director” : “Alpha Ly”,
  “actors” : [
    “Alpha Ly”,
    “Kris Dasha”,
    “Hope Grace”
  ]
}
```

When I check my collection in Compass, I don’t see the document with the ObjectId("5f8884fed29ded706c3c6737

However, when I run the following command `db.practice.find({"director": "Alpha Ly"}).pretty()`,
it returns the entry I've looking for in Compass.

NB: the number of documents in my collection is still the same as created.
What seems to be the problem here. Why Compass is not displaying the entry?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was not using the correct database.
In order to execute the command, I was supposed to use the `use` command followed by the name of my database to switch to my database. Since I didn't, the update query created another collection and inserted the document there. Therefore, I couldn't find it in my database.
Thanks